# How to add tokens inline within a UITextView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitextview

I would like to add tokens or buttons inline in a UITextView. I was thinking of trying to embed NSTokenFields inside a UITextView? I don't know if this is an optimal way to go about it. I would appreciation any sort of direction on how to accomplish this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSTokenField doesn't exist on iOS.

Take a look at https://github.com/jasarien/JSTokenField -- it's not perfect, but it's a fair simulation.

Comment: I was modifying this earlier but I wanted to use a textview instead of a textfield and realized it'd take a lot of tweaking. I guess it's the only option.